# How to get two different value for same reference id in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table:
1) Product
2) Item

Product table:

```
PId  Name   value1  value2
1    abc    1233    4567
2    xyz    9099    9099
```

Item Table:

```
itemId  itemname  item_start   item_end
1        idc         1            2
```

item_start & item_end are the reference of product table on column PId.

Now when i write below query:

```
select * from item left join product on item_start = PId and item_end = PId
```

then it gives only value1 data but i want data like :

```
itemId  itemname  item_start  item_start_value1 item_start_value2  item_end    item_end_value1    item_end_value2
1        idc         1           1233               4567               2            9099            9099
```

How can i get the above output?

Comment: it's called self join :)

Answer (score 1):

Join the product table twice.

```
SELECT item.*
     , productStart.Value1 AS product_start_value1
     , productStart.Value2 AS product_start_value2
     , productEnd.Value1 AS product_end_value1
     , productEnd.Value2 AS product_end_value2
  FROM item
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN product productStart
    ON productStart.PId = item.item_start
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN product productEnd
    ON productEnd.PId = item.item_end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have 2 FKs on item table, you'd need 2 joins on product table.

```
SELECT I.itemId, I.itemname, I.item_start, P1.value1 as item_start_value1, P1.value2 as item_start_value2, I.item_end, P2.value1 as item_end_value1, P2.value2 as item_end_value2
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN product P1 ON item_start = PId 
LEFT JOIN product P2 ON item_end = PId
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of what can be done:

```
select * from #Item i inner join #Product p on i.item_Start = p.Pid
inner join #Product p2 on i.Item_end = p2.PId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT item.itemId
     , item.itemname
     , item.item_start
     , productStart.Value1 AS item_start_value1
     , productStart.Value2 AS item_start_value2
     , item.item_end 
     , productEnd.Value1 AS item_end_value1
     , productEnd.Value2 AS item_end_value2
  FROM item
  Inner JOIN product productStart ON productStart.PId = item.item_start
  Inner JOIN product productEnd  ON productEnd.PId = item.item_end
```

Comment: I don't see why this would get a downvote.  I prefer `left join`, but this answers the question.